# Error trying to run project. Access is denied (But user has access to the project folder)

Tags: visual-studio, security, exe, access-denied

I can't seem to run a simple console application that just prints out `"Hello World"` and then a `Readline()` to end the program.

**NB**, this happens only on my work PC. I don't have this problem on my personal PC.

I explain what I have done.

```
Visual Studio: Community 2022 (64-bit) - Version 17.8.5
OS: Windows 11 Business Version 10.0.22631
```

In Visual Studio, when I run the project I get the following error:

> Error while trying to run project: Unable to start program [PATH TO
> EXE FILE]

> Access is denied

[image]

I then open the project folder in **Windows Explorer** and manually run the exe file in the *Debug* folder. I get a similar error message with slight different wording that says:

> Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not
> have the appropriate permissions to access the item.

[image]

It seems like there is a user rights problem. I open the security properties of the containing folder and notice that my user is mentioned and it has **Full Control** authority over the folder.

[image]

Mind that in my *Windows Security* settings, I have also tried deactivating the **Reputation-based Protection** to allow running unrecognized apps and files. Althrough, this is not recommended, but I have done it just to see if it makes any difference.

[image]

As I said, none of this is required in my personal PC where I run the exact same program. I am running out of ideas where to look.

Answer (score 1):

The likely cause is:

1. Microsoft Defender exploit Guard, new default aggressive rules for attack surface reduction
2. Our IT administrator team now even block vanilla apps.exe

See Event Viewer -> Application and service logs -> `/Microsoft/Windows/Windows Defender/Operational`

In my case, I see events that indicate threat protection is the cause.

Here is the copilot translation of my french error message from eventvwr:

```
Microsoft Defender Exploit Guard has blocked an operation that is not authorized by your IT administrator. 
For more information, contact your IT administrator. 
ID: 01443614-CD74-433A-B99E-2ECDC07BFC25 
Detection Duration: 2024-01-22T20:10:46.962Z 
User: _ 
Path: C:\Users_\source\repos____.exe 
Process Name: C:\Windows\explorer.exe 
Target Command Line: 
Parent Command Line: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE 
Affected Folder: 
Inheritance Indicator: 0x00000000 
Security Intelligence Version: 1.403.2529.0 
Engine Version: 1.1.23110.2 
Product Version: 4.18.23110.3
```

Original French event:

```
Microsoft Defender exploit Guard a bloqué une opération qui n’est pas autorisée par votre administrateur informatique.
 pour plus d’informations, contactez votre administrateur informatique.
    ID : 01443614-CD74-433A-B99E-2ECDC07BFC25
    Durée de détection : 2024-01-22T20:10:46.962Z
    Utilisateur : ____\____
    Chemin d’accès : C:\Users\____\source\repos\______.exe
    Nom du processus :  C:\Windows\explorer.exe
    Ligne de commande cible : 
    Ligne de commande parents : C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
    Dossier concerné : 
    Indicateur d'héritage : 0x00000000
    Version de la veille de sécurité : 1.403.2529.0
    Version du moteur : 1.1.23110.2
    Version du produit : 4.18.23110.3
```

Comment: Thank you! I checked *Event Viewer*, and I seem to get the same error. I will contact our IT Administrator.